# What is the meaning of this code and what do {} brackets mean?

Tags: c#

I am making a rock, paper, scissors, lizard, Spock game. I already did it and it works perfectly! But there is a line of code that I've been using for two days now and I don't know the meaning of. Here it is:

```
{weapon2chose[bot_weapon_chosen]}
```

I use it in order to take a random word from a string array and then print the word instead of just a number with the random class like this:

```
Console.WriteLine($"You fought against {weapon2chose[bot_weapon_chosen]} and lost...");
```

This is the random code I use as well:

```
string[] weapon2chose = {"rock", "paper", "scissors", "lizard", "Spock" }; 
Random and = new Random(); 
int bot_weapon_chosen = rnd.Next(weapon2chose.Length);
```

I'd like you to explain to me what the `{}` brackets are and how does it print out a string instead of a number.

Comment: It's called [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)

Answer (score 1):

This is called [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated). When a string constant begins with `$`, the curly braces are where you put replacement values.

For example:

```
int i = 55;
Console.WriteLine($"Value is {i}.");
```

The output is:

> Value is 55.